# Strange behaviour with void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void

I want to create a function which gets a void pointer. This pointer points to an arbitrary user data. This is not relevant now. Which is more important a descriptor, which describe this user data. It is **under this data**. I want to get it's address, there are two different solution:

```
struct data_desc {
     size_t size;
     data_type_t type;
     /* And so on... */
};

/* Operate on the descriptor */
void operate_on_data(void *ptr)
{
    struct data_desc *desc;
    /* Now I want to get the desc /*

    /* This is the first approach, simply fails */
    desc = ((struct data_desc *)ptr) - sizeof(struct data_desc);
    /* This is the second, it works...*/
    desc = (struct data_desc *)ptr;
    desc--; 
    /* Do something with desc */
}
```

As you can see I use two diffrent approach **to get the descriptor's address**. I thought the first is more natural, but it's just not works. I used more parentheses to avoid the precedence problems.

I know that these methods *are not safe*. **The first does not work, why?** What is the reason behind this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clear some things up? What does ptr point to? to type or size, or what?

Comment: This will be a memory allocator, the ptr passed to the user, so it can be any user data. To organize these chunks the descriptor store some information about this, size and the pointers of the previous and the second chunk. When the free() comes, it only gets the ptr, so it must get the information somehow. The easiest way to do this, is to attach it to the user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pointer arithmetic.  When you take a pointer and subtract 1, you are really subtracting `(1*sizeof(struct))`.  The first equation with the "-sizeof", you are really subtracting `(sizeof(struct) * sizeof(struct))` bytes from the pointer.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

When you define `data_desc` as a pointer to a `struct data_desc`, the compiler knows to add or subtract `sizeof(struct data_desc)` when you increment or decrement the pointer by one.  In other words, it translates "one" into "one structure."

It's common to write code like this:

```
struct data_desc *desc = (struct data_desc *) ptr;
```

Then you can manipulate it like this:

```
size_t sz0 = desc->size;  // size of 0th element
size_t sz1 = desc[1].size;  // size of 1st element
size_t sz2 = (desc + 2)->size; // size of 2nd element (slightly awkward)
desc++;  // Increment to next structure
```

Back to your original code:  you *could* write `desc = ((struct data_desc *)ptr) - 1;`, but most programmers would prefer to initialize `desc` and then use it directly.

Comment: You are right. The first case also do this. The subtraction from the ptr is like decreasing the desc by one. I think the problem lies in the type sizes. IMHO it should work with a char pointer, because it is only one byte wide, the sizeof(struct desc_data) is also in bytes.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  If you're saying you could define `char *desc` and then use your original calculation, you're right ... but then you can't dereference `desc` because it points to a `char`, not to a `data_desc` structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
desc = ((struct data_desc *)ptr) - sizeof(struct data_desc);
```

You've typecast `ptr` to a `struct data_desc *`. Now, all arithmetic that the compiler does on this pointer is in chunks the size of the type it points to.

So, if you subtract `sizeof(struct data_desc)` (let's say `struct  data_desc` is 8 bytes in size), `ptr` will point to a location that can fit 8 `struct data_desc` in between itself and `ptr`.

Assuming each `loc` below can hold one `struct data_desc`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| loc | loc | loc | loc | loc | loc | loc | loc | loc | ptr | 
|  9  |  8  |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
      ^                                               ^
      |                                               |
     desc                                            ptr 
     location                                        location
     after
     subtraction
```